# SSRS: Passing a BIGINT as parameter to subreport

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, bigint

When working in SSRS I saw the following problem:

One of the fields in main report's dataset was of a BIGINT type.
I tried to implement a click through to a different report passing this field's value, however the report would not accept the parameter and leave the text box blank without any error messages displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem is type incompatibility. Because SSRS does not support BIGINT data type natively, you have to convert a BIGINT value to a string before passing it to subreport. You can do it in the stored procedure which generates the dataset for parent report... Or you can do it when passing this parameter to subreport, which I preferred.

Instead of passing =Fields![FieldName].Value on click, you have to pass **=Fields![FieldName].Value.ToString()**

Profit!!!